# Manual editing after 'git checkout -p'

Tags: git, vim

I want to undo some changes from unstaged changes. For that I ran:

```
$ git checkout -p
```

Then I selected the **e** option for manual editing the hunk I was interested in and pressed ENTER:

```
@@ -320,6 +326,7 @@ public class TtsPresenterImpl implements TtsPresenter {
     public void onStopClicked() {
         model.stopPlayList();
         model.loadCurrentFile();
+
     }

     public static List<String> getFiles(File dir, String regex, boolean recursive) {
Discard this hunk from worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,K,j,J,g,e,?]? e
```

The help at the bottom told me:

```
# To remove '+' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '-' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
```

So I replaced the + with a space. I use VIM so I placed the cursor at that position and then pressed r followed by a space. For those who don't use VIM - this is a command to replace the character under cursor with a space. No more, no less.

But after I saved the changes and left the editor with `:x` command
Git notified me:

```
fatal: corrupt patch at line 26
Your edited hunk does not apply. Edit again (saying "no" discards!) [y/n]?
```

What's the problem? I expected the change to be undone. I also tried it with # as suggested in help, but with the same result.

Please don't suggest discarding the hunk. Yes, it works, but I think there is a general problem with manual editing. It already happened to me that I 'removed' just a line in a method, but the whole method disappeared after that. This is strange.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.7.4
```

Another try (hunk with 2 changes). The goal is to keep the change `y` but undo the `x` change:

```
@@ -50,8 +50,9 @@ public class TtsModelImpl implements TtsModel, Serializable {
         listeners = new ArrayList<>();
         state = State.PLAYLIST_STOPPED;
         sentenceIterator = new TextSplitterForTts();
-
+        x
         load();
+        y
     }

     @Override
Discard this hunk from worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,s,e,?]? e
```

After I replaced the + with space in the x-line I got the following

```
...
        x
        load();
    }
```

Where is `y`?

Comment: The line has been added, removing the plus doesn’t make sense to me. I think you need to remove the line as well.

Comment: @evolutionxbox But the help says clearly how to remove added lines.

Comment: Odd. Maybe I’m thinking about patch when adding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t make a hunk that doesn’t change anything; you’ll have to use y/n in this situation. The same problem doesn’t extend to manual editing in general.

However, going by some phrases in your description:

> I expected the change to be undone.

> Please don't suggest discarding the hunk. Yes, it works

you were trying to remove the line from your working tree. When Git explains how “to remove '+' lines”, in the context of `git checkout -p`, that’s removing them *from the patch to be discarded*. That could account for your disappearing method.

To deal with this in a more intuitive and reversible way, one option would be to `git add -p` changes you want to keep, make a temporary commit, discard uncommitted changes, and reset the temporary commit.

Comment: Is there somewhere to read up on how the line count works? I’ve never really understood them.

Comment: Changing the line number didn't help.

Comment: @ka3ak: It’s not the line number; it’s the number of lines before and after the patch. In your example, if replacing the `+` with a space, `-320,6` should become `-320,7`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: ^. `@@ -w,x +y,z @@` means that the following text represents `x` lines starting with line `w` changing to `z` lines. (`y` changes because of line count differences in preceding hunks.)

Comment: @Ry I may have used a wrong word for this, but the change from 6 to 7 didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Git re-counts the lines (using `git apply --recount`) so there is no need to adjust the `@@` lines. This is a rather different problem...

Comment: @ka3ak: Oh, okay. It looks like that’s because there are no changes in the resulting patch; you’re just going to have to use y/n.

Comment: @Ry Please try to insert 2 empty lines at 2 different places in a file. And then try to undo one of them using the method described in the question. I'm afraid it's not obvious how to achieve it. I constantly get "fatal: corrupt patch at line..." Of course you aren't obliged to do it, but I think that it would make our discussion more productive.

Comment: @ka3ak: I did (it’s what I was originally testing, hence the incorrect `,7` advice – sorry). Are your empty lines in the same hunk?

Comment: I have just managed to do some changes so that I get a hunk with 2 changes displayed, but still couldn't figure out how to undo one of them...
Would be great to have a link to a guide, but what I've googled so far contained just a reference to the git help.

Comment: @ka3ak: Remember, you’re constructing a reverse patch. Leave the changes you want to undo alone in the editor, and alter all the ones you want to *keep* – `+` to space, `-` removed. As far as a guide… frankly, I’d just never do this on the working tree, since it’s easy to get wrong and have discard changes permanently, compared to `git add -p` where you can try again.

Comment: @Ry I appended the use case with 2 changes in a hunk to the question.

Comment: @ka3ak: Again: with `git checkout -p`, you’re creating a reverse patch. The changes that stay in the patch are the ones that get thrown out. Replace the `+` on the *y* line with space.